# Create a menu in XAML

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app

My question is pretty basic. I want to make a menu in XAML.
Let's say I have the main page with option 1 and option 2. I want a new page to open when I click option 1 and a new one when I click option 3. How do I do that? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Generally you want to show some effort first as this is a Q&A site for specific programming problems, and not a tutorial site. There are tons of freely available tutorials out there on the interwebs for this exact thing easily found with a quick trip to your favorite search engine. Come on back when you run into a specific roadblock in your attempt. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's pretty simple. 
Add to your XAML

```
 <Page.TopAppBar>
    <CommandBar IsOpen="False" ClosedDisplayMode="Minimal">
        <CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
<AppBarButton x:Name="btnOption1" Label="Option1 Page" Click="btnOption1_Click" Icon="Play"  >
<AppBarButton x:Name="btnOption2" Label="Option2 Page" Click="btnOption2_Click" Icon="Setting"  >
            </AppBarButton>
        </CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.TopAppBar>
```

When you click on button code would be

```
   private void btnOption1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      // this code loading XAML page with name Option1Page
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Option1Page));
    }
       private void btnOption2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Option2Page));
    }
```

Now you need also create Option1Page.xaml and Option2Page.xaml